# Looking for specifications for Wilson Electronics WAU 420 amplifier

Tags: uhf, mobile, amplifier, equipment-operation

Hey there helpful people I'm trying to track down some specifications on a Wilson Electronics WAU 420. I have no idea on its exact age but guessing its from the late 90's. It's likely UHF band and probably 12v DC. The other end is just the Wilson Electronics Logo.

[image: WAU 420 Amateur Amplifier]

Ideally I'd like to get these numbers before I try to operate it. I'll be posting a different question to try and run down the power connector part number so this will just be the specs unless someone turns up a manual.

- Input frequency range:
- Input power min/max:
- Output Power min/max:
- Expected Duty Cycle:
- Current draw min/max:

I've tried searching online and because of the model number I get more drug related hits than I can filter out.

Wilson Electronics no longer does anything but Cell Boosters(amps). Wilson support suggested contacting RoadPro (I have) which purchased the Wilson Antenna brand, but they are mostly CB/antenna/headset focused. (RP Support asked if I had the box).

Comment: "FCC DATA WAU 420" makes it sound like an equipment approval identifier, rather than a model number? Unfortunately I'm not seeing anything online (via e.g. https://fccid.io/) for that FCC ID — perhaps it pre-dates their online records? IIUC, equipment manufacturers get to ± self-assign those identifiers though, so it might not be unreasonable to assume it was for signals around 420 MHz?

Comment: Is there any additional information on the circuit board itself, inside the case?

Comment: Is there any info inside (say, on the PCB)? Also, a photo of the board might tell us the band. Could you edit your question and add one?

Comment: My first thought was this might be a CB amplifier. Those "UHF" SO-239 connectors are not suitable for anything over 220 MHz because they introduce a significant impedance bump (and thus a mismatch) . That's partly why I asked for a photo of the "guts". Heck, that FCC label might be phony for all we know,  an attempt to make a CB amp look like it's legal, etc. :-)

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this I just have had other higher priority things to work on. I'll get some internal pictures this week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I opened the case I was able to tell that it was a low-power amp.

The amplifier chip SD1429 (Pill) was expecting 2 watts in and was rated for about 15 watts out in the 70cm band. The heatsink was way oversized for that use and had small threaded taps for a circuit board about double in size. Potentially you could route the RF into a second stage amp for more power within the same case.

[image: Inside the Amplifier]